# Rspec undefined method `belong_to'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using RSpec 3.10 and trying to test a belongs_to relationship

```
RSpec.describe MyClasss, type: :model do
  it { is_expected.to belong_to(:another_class) }
end

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `belong_to' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyClasss
```

Do I need a special configuration in order to use belong_to matcher?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the `shoulda-matchers` gem installed

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I set up my test incorrectly.  Here's what I had:

```
describe MyModel do
```

and here's what worked:

```
RSpec.describe MyModel, type: :model do
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're working on a Rails app, simply place this at the bottom of spec/rails_helper.rb (or in a support file if you so choose):

```html
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```